# Trying to understand flow control/charting

Tags: python, loops

```
import sys

access = False
while not access:
    username = input('Enter username: ')
    if username.lower() != 'joe':
        print("imposter!")
        continue
    
    else:
        print(f'Hello {username.capitalize()}')
        for i in range(3):
            password = input('Enter password: ')
            if password == 'Water':
                access = True
                break
        else:
            print("3 strikes, you're out")
            sys.exit()

print("Access granted")
```

[image: My attempt at making a flowchart]
Is this the proper flowchart for this code? I'm trying to understand **how to properly draw flowcharts** with **for loops**.  I'm teaching myself through 'Automate the Boring Things in Python'

Comment: Your flow chart looks mostly correct to me. What is your actual question for us? Stack Overflow's question and answer format isn't really designed for general discussion, so this question without an actual question may get closed, though you can try to [edit] it into a better format. Check out [ask] for guidance on what fits our site better.

Comment: No, the `break` exits only the `for` loop, not the outer `while`.

Comment: @blckknght my question was 'is the flowchart correctly drawn?' as stated in the body of the post.  And breaking the 'for' loop would bring it back up to the start of the while loop.. changing the while not Access = True, into while not Access = False... thus bringing it down to the final print statement and ending the program.  Wouldn't that be the case or is my logic wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your program looks quite well following your flowchart, However, to complete it without having to explicitly invoking the exit() function and END the flow at the end of the module, consider introducing a new flag, I called mine **bol_access_denied**. Really, it could be called by any name:

```
import sys

bol_access_denied = False  # You will need to introduce a flag before you enter your while...loop.
access = False
while not access:
    username = input('Enter username: ')
    if username.lower() != 'joe':
        print("imposter!")
        continue
    
    # else:  # This else can be omitted since program flows here ONLY when username == joe 
    print(f'Hello {username.capitalize()}')
    for i in range(3):
        password = input('Enter password: ')
        if password == 'Water':
            access = True
            break
    else:
        print("3 strikes, you're out")
        bol_access_denied = True  # set the flag here.
        # sys.exit()  This can be replaced by 'break', then backed by [see STEP Final-Check]
    if bol_access_denied:  # Test the flag here.
        break

if access:  # STEP Final-Check, is to navigate the user to a personalized section of your program.
    print("Access granted")

# Your program ends here naturally without explicitly invoking the exit function.
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This was great and easy to follow along with.  Thank you for the pointers!  I don't understand the point of the flag though. It seems like it does the same thing as access.  Is the flag like double checking?

Comment: @pythonpaul007, thank you for your kind comment. You are right, but my solution work-around is a caveat for readability sake. To help anyone understand better. Although, the **Test the flag here** section can also be replaced with **if not access: break** based on how your code is structured. I'm just hoping not to confuse you as to why it would work. Please, feel free to up-vote and mark as solution to help others.